# PHP, JavaScript, Combination

Tags: php, javascript, combinations

I have some Condition at PHP and if it's true i need php variable to get javascript function:
Something like that:

```
<?php
if(x == true){
$x = <script type="text/javascript">xfunction();</script>;
}
?>
```

I don't really know how to get them to combination.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need PHP variable to get JavaScript function"?  You won't be able to actually _execute_ JavaScript code in your PHP code, but you can use PHP to conditionally include JavaScript on the resulting page.

Comment: I read the answers thanks, and i mean that there is a PHP var ($x) and i want him to contain javascript function, and all of that will happen if the PHP condition is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invoke a function *onload* when rendering your document.. you can just `echo` out a self executing function.

```
<?php 
 // your other code
 if( $x ) { // no need to check if true... this will fail if falsey 
   echo "<script>";
   echo "(function() { xfunction(); }());"; // I will execute when the parser hits me
   echo "</script>";
 }
 // or (after reading your comments above) 
 if( $x ) { 
   $x  = "";
   $x .= "<script>";
   $x .= "(function() { xfunction(); }());"; // I will execute when the parser hits me
   $x .= "</script>";
 }
 // somewhere else in the document.... 
 echo $x;
```

or if you are trying to pass values from javascript to php you will need to make use of HTTP Request variables (POST, GET) or XHR...

Example of the XHR:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
request.open('POST', 'http://www.somepage.com/foo.php', true);  
request.send('data=somedata');  

if (request.status === "200") {  
  console.log(request.responseText);  
}
```

and on the php end of like access it with `$_POST['data']`

More reading can be done about PHP Request variables [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

More information regarding XHR can be read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: self executing function might be overkill... but hey! why not.

Comment: Thank You rlemon for you answer, Have a Nice Day.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if($x){
        print '<script type="text/javascript">xfunction();</script>;';
    }
?>
```

Should works, if I understand your question?